# VSTO Outlook 2013 Addin Quit

Tags: c#, dialog, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a VSTO addin that displays a a dialog box with buttons yes no and cancel.  I want the form to close anytime cancel or the X are clicked.  I also want the application to quit when the form is closed.  Here is my code:

```
        var frm = new Form1();
        DialogResult res = frm.ShowDialog();

        if (client != null)
        {
            if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                path = DRIVE_LETTER + ":/Clients/" + client + "/Correspondence/";
            }
            else if (res == DialogResult.No)
            {
                path = DRIVE_LETTER + ":/Clients Project History/" + client + "/Correspondence/";
            }
            else if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                frm.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                frm.Close();
            }
```

And then my form closing event handler:

```
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application doesn't have an Exit method.  How can I do the equivalent from within VSTO?  I want my application to stop executing completely when those forms are canceled/closed.

Thanks

EDIT: can anyone provide an example of quitting the addin.  Or stopping all execution if a certain condition is met, like Pyton's sys.exit().  I don't want outlook to close, just the addin to stop execution.  Not even unload, just stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to shut down Outlook you may use the [Quit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866010.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Application class. The associated Outlook session will be closed completely; the user will be logged out of the messaging system and any changes to items not already saved will be discarded.

But if you need to shut down the add-in (not the host application) you can:

1. Disable all event handlers and UI controls. To get the job done you may check out the global boolean variable which can indicate the state of the add-in (allowed to run or not).
2. The [Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.comaddin.connect.aspx) property of the ComAddIn class allows to set the state of the connection for the specified COMAddIn object. The property returns true if the add-in is active; it returns false if the add-in is inactive. An active add-in is registered and connected; an inactive add-in is registered but not currently connected.

   ```
   Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();

   if (outlook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect)
   {
       outlook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect = false;
   }
   else
   {
       outlook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect = true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Forgive my stupidity,  would it be possible to show me a short example of what you mean for numbers 1  and 2?

Comment: Which is the boolean global that inidicates the addin state?

Comment: You need to use your own (define it yourself).

Comment: Yeah I haven't a clue how to do that, any examples or guides you can give me?  I looked over your Connect docs but still can't figure it out. Sorry :(

Comment: Outlook.Application OutLook = new Outlook.Application();

     if (OutLook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect)
     {
         Outlook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect = false;
      }
      else
      {
          Outlook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect = true;
      }